# Hosted subversion recommendations or suggestions

Tags: svn, hosting, saas

I'm investigating using hosted subversion for a new project at work and was wondering if anyone had any experiences they would share.

I've personally used [Beanstalk](http://www.beanstalkapp.com/) for small projects at home, but not with mulitple users or a large repository.

What/who have you used?

For what size/type of project?

What was your experience? (Uptime, performance, customer service, etc.)

Comment: customer service ? what kind of customer service could there be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wush.net has been awesome - great support
I use it for personal projects as well as two freelance projects (one with a few hundred thousand lines of code)
None have large number of developers, but that should not be a problem

svnrepository is also good - but a lot less hand holding.
I switched to wush only because I did not want to have to do so much of the admin - mostly for the trac stuff.  They also had good support, but you are responsible for a lot more of the admin.

I have not experienced any downtime that I noticed.  (either for svn or trac)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297153/can-you-recommend-a-svn-closed-source-project-hosting-site#297180

there are also other SO questions on this topic...
a search of svn and hosting should bring them up

Comment: see the other question, linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com).... They have a free plan plus some other nice project management type functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using DreamHost because I really didn't like the restrictions imposed by the "subversion-only" hosts, e.g. really small space or few repositories.

I want to be able to check in everything related to the build without having to think about the space limitation.

It's cheap ($10 a month) and practically unlimited disk space (and unlimited users and repositories).  Haven't experienced any downtime so for but is sometimes a bit slow.

The only downside is that they have subversion v. 1.4.2 and I haven't had great success upgrading.  But someone with a Linux experience would probably be able to do it in no time :)

Comment: I am unsing dreamhost too... one restriction I find is that you cannot set user permission

Answer (score 0):

If your project is open-source, you might want consider Google Code.

I've found it to be excellent!

Answer (score 0):

I used [wush.net](http://www.wush.net) for a while for small personal projects and never had any problems... service was reliable and speedy.  I terminated my account there once I moved my web hosting to a provider that also supported svn.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with [mikeymo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4398/mikeymo) [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com) is a great ticketing and subversion host.  They have a free account that I have been using for almost a year now and is great.  It takes so much work out of development, especially when dealing with tasks and related commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can always deploy your own version control server with Subversion and VisualSVN Server in the cloud. You need a Windows-based virtual machine in MS Azure or AWS.

The installation procedure is very simple and you will get a powerful hosted version control server. See the [Getting Started guide](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/getting-started/) for installation instructions.