# svn server on shared hosting

Tags: .net, svn, open-source

I'm looking for an open source svn server which I can install from web. (like wordpress installation) Because of shared hosting.

I will connect svn server from with visual studio.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on a classical shared hosting package.

Subversion requires the installation of a service, and usually also integration with Apache. This can not be done without the help of the hosting provider's administrator (who usually won't change the setup of their racks for one customer.)

There are hosting companies who offer Subversion as an additional service. I have heard [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/) being mentioned favourably on SO in that context.

Related:

- [Hosted subversion recommendations or suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299990/hosted-subversion-recommendations-or-suggestions)
- [Opinion of Hosted SVN providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384/opinion-of-hosted-svn-providers)
- [More](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subversion+hosting)

Comment: thanks Pekka. Do you know Origo ? http://www.origo.ethz.ch

Comment: @Jack nope, but looks interesting!