# Hosted VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

Looking to implement VisualSVN but I don't have my own server. I could install it locally and run it on my PC but if something happens to my PC I will lose everything.

So servers out there that provide an SVN service or provide hosted VisualSVN Server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use ProjectLocker (http://www.projectlocker.com/). It's cheap and the service is good. But there's plenty of hosted subversion providers out there.

Google Code is an good option if you're doing open source.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN is just a wrapper product around [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion). What you are looking for is a hosted Subversion service.

Related questions:

- [Opinion of Hosted SVN providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384/opinion-of-hosted-svn-providers)
- [Hosted subversion recommendations or suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299990/hosted-subversion-recommendations-or-suggestions)

However, if you need only local access to the repository, you could as well set up a local server, and do frequent backups. There are very affordable remote backup providers with whom it is possible to automate the process - probably cheaper (and faster) than remotely hosted SVN.

On the other hand, if you do team work, remotely hosted version control is clearly the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can install VisualSVN Server in the cloud. For example, you can easily install it on a VM in MS Azure or AWS.
2. You can install VisualSVN Server on your PC and [enable repository backup to Azure Files](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00133/).

Answer (score -1):

look up svn hosting service providers. You can pick one according to your project and team size and the number of projects.